# How to balance text spread around a circle

Tags: design-principles, critique

I am an amateur Inkscape user designing a logo for an upcoming event. We want the logo to be circular so it can be printed on round beer mats etc. The text 'Granite' is longer than the other text 'Bowl' and '2017' and I am struggling to make the text look balanced. I have tried adding some blood splatter after 'Bowl'. Is there a different way to position the text to make it look balanced? Is there any other things I could add around the circle to help?

[image]

**Edit:**
In response to Scotts answer below

[image]

Comment: Looking good now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically...

- Do *not* use italics for the text.
- Do not add multiple spaces between words
- Center the text at the top of the circle.

Multiple, different length, words will look fine with a standard single space between them. It is when you add additional spaces and use italics that the visual "group" is broken and you start seeing each word as a separate entity. Larger word spacing may work in some cases if that's part of your design, but if you are concerned with balance, treat both words as a single object, centered around the top.